# How to Get a Smooth Curve?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

I have created a long cylinder with lots of loop cuts:

[image]

When I apply this to a curve, the result is still very 'chunky':

[image]

My curve modifier is like this:

[image]

Is there a way to get a smoother curve?

Comment: Increase the *(Preview) Resolution* of the curve in the curves data settings.

Comment: Where are these settings?

Comment: In the [properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/properties_editor.html) editor, press the curve icon. Change *Preview U* in the [shape section](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/curves/properties/data.html#shape).

Comment: Fantastic! Could you please add this as an answer?